# when clicking link a:visited dont work, diff color

Tags: css

When you see the site http://colin.amsterdam you see the social links in the top, when you click on it (the Facebook and Instagram links) it become blue again. In the CSS I put the yellow color in it for the a:visited one, but it's not working. Anyone ideas?

```css
body {
 background-color: #0d2481;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-family: 'Contrail One', cursive;
 font-size: 20px;
 overflow-x: hidden;
}

img {
 border: 0;
}

.main {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
 text-align: right;
 font-family: 'Contrail One', cursive;
 color: #ffdb30;
}

.main a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
 color: #ffdb30;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.main-head {
 font-family: 'Contrail One', cursive;
 color: #ffdb30;
 font-size: 80px;
}

.aside {
 height: 100%;
 background-color: #ffdb30;
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
 font-family: 'Contrail One', cursive;
 color: #0d2481;
}

.aside a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active {
 color: #0d2481;
 text-decoration:none;
}

.aside-head {
 font-family: 'Contrail One', cursive;
 color: #0d2481;
 font-size: 80px;
}

.space {
 height:20px;
}

.clearfix:after {
 content:"";
 display:table;
 clear:both;
}
```

Comment: correct your selector `.aside a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active` it should be `.aside a:link, aside a:visited, aside a:hover, aside a:active`

Comment: You forgot the class dots for pretty much every aside yourself, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your rules.

Here you set the color to yellow:
`.main a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active`

and here you set it to blue:
`.aside a:link, a:visited, a:hover, a:active`.

If you want to style every link in a different way, you need to add the `class` before every rule like this:

```css
/* Color for every link */
a:link, 
a:visited, 
a:hover, 
a:active {
  color: red;
}
/* Color for every link ONLY in .main */
.main a:link, 
.main a:visited, 
.main a:hover, 
.main a:active {
  color: blue;
}
/* Color for every link ONLY in .aside */
.aside a:link, 
.aside a:visited,
.aside a:hover, 
.aside a:active {
  color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Testlink</a>
<div class="main"><a href="#">Testlink with main</a></div>
<div class="aside"><a href="#">Testlink with aside</a></div>
```